# Unity Hub stuck in loading screen after installing on Ubunty 22.04

Tags: 22.04, launcher

I installed Unity through the [official Unity instructions](https://docs.unity3d.com/hub/manual/InstallHub.html#install-hub-linux) and it didn't work so I tried downloading it through other ways mentioned by other threads ([here](https://dev.to/brenomfviana/installing-unity-hub-on-ubuntu-42l0) and [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/installing-unity-hub-on-ubuntu-22-04.1271816/)). Right after downloading I am able to log into my Unity account and install the Unity version I want to install, but once I quit the Hub and try to open it again, it gets stuck on the loading page, like in the picture. I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on a second SATA SSD disk connected to my laptop. I'm wondering if anyone has had the same problem and if you were able to solve this issue. I am not able to open nor create new projects so having it installed is virtually useless. Thanks.

[loading screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNSqj.png)